# Ruby OAuth2 client

Tags: ruby, oauth, google-oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to create a script to access the [Quizlet API](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow)

Those API are protected with OAuth2 and I'm using this `oauth2` ruby gem https://github.com/intridea/oauth2

The gem's GitHub page shows an example but for me doesn't work and I feel I'm missing some pieces.
This is part of the example:

```
client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback')
# => "https://example.org/oauth/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback"

token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic some_password'})
```

Two quetions:

- What should I do with the result of `authorize_url`?  This url should be opened on a browser to proceed with the login, but the gem doesn't open it automatically. Should I ask the user to do so?
- What about the callback URL? The example uses `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback` but is not clear if the gem itelf is in charge of listening on that port.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to look at what the Quizlet API is asking you to do, and skipping the integration with the oauth gem. I could be wrong and I'd be interested to see how the the gem is used, but it's still a good idea to look at how to implement an oauth client step-by-step.

This is taken from the Quizlet API docs:

1. Send the user to `https://quizlet.com/authorize`. This can be done by displaying a link for the user to click, or redirecting server-side.
2. Once the user accepts/denies your oauth (this happens on the quizlet website, not your own), quizlet will send a request to your server. Because of the `/authorize` call, Quizlet will now have a `redirect_uri` which they will use to get in touch with your server. In your server's action for this route, you can get the `authorization_code`.
3. Send the `authorization_code` to `https://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token`, and in the response get an `access_token` whic you use for the rest of the api requests.

---

About the gem

- You should send the authorize url to users. This is step 1 above
- the gem is not in charge of listening for the redirect. You need to use a web server for this.

Comment: Thanks @max-pleaner I read the documentation and I'm able to interact with the api with some `curl` and `bash` magic. The question is more related to the `gem`, I still don't understand if the gem provides also the webserver.

Comment: @IgnazioC ok updated answer, hopefully covers some of your question about the gem